# Unit tests: TestRestTemplate GET request returns different ResponseEntity than actual

Tags: spring-boot, exception

I've written a unit tests which tries to get a non-existing entity from database. Here it is:

```
/**
* {@code GET /api/entity/{id}} - check GET request of a non-existing entity (id not found).
*/
@Test
public void getEntityNotExistingTest() {
   ResponseEntity<String> getResponse = restTemplate
            .getForEntity("/api/entity/9999", String.class);
        
   assertThat(getResponse.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

Test passes, but when I print the actual body of this `ResponseEntity` by: `getResponse.getBody()` it differs from the body I get by making the very same testing by myself in Postman.
In the above unit test I get: `{"timestamp":"2023-06-23T13:25:37.326+00:00","status":404,"error":"Not Found","path":"/api/entity/9999"}`.
Pretty print:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2023-06-23T13:25:37.326+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": Not Found,
    "path": "/api/entity/9999"
}
```

However, the response body I get in Postman - which is the one I'm aiming for, by the way - is the following:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2023-06-23T13:27:27.758+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "Unable to find entity of 9999 id",
    "path": "/api/entity/9999"
}
```

As you can see, the `message` key is missing in the unit test. Why is that?
**Note**: This is how the JSON is produced:

```
public Entity get(Long entityId) {
    Optional<Entity> optEntity = entityRepository.findById(entityId);
    if(optEntity.isEmpty()) {
        throw new EntityNotFoundException(entityId);
    }
    return optEntity.get();
}
```

And the `EntityNotFoundException` looks like this:

```
@ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class EntityNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

    public EntityNotFoundException (Long id) {
        super("Unable to find entity of %d id".formatted(id));
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect your test case rest template is unable to find the endpoint you are trying to consume and hence 404 not found error is thrown. Please log and check the stacktrace for more information.

Comment: Hi @Rishal, thanks for answering. I've included `server.error.include-stacktrace=always` to `application.properties`. Here's what I get now:
```{
"timestamp":"2023-06-23T13:54:36.159+00:00",
"status":404,
"error":"Not Found",
"trace":"com.demo.example.exceptions.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find entity of 9999 id\r\n\tat com.demo.example.api.services.EntityService.get(EntityService.java:26)\r\n\tat com.demo.example.api.controllers.EntityController.getEntity(EntityController.java:33)...",
"path":"/api/entity/9999"}
```

As you can see, it does find the endpoint. I'm clueless :D

Comment: Please create a Minimal, Reproducible Example to check further as it not much clear and also identifying the behaviour with these details is not enough.